# Capture packets and redirect them using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I am posting this question after doing a lot of searching about SCAPY, i saw that it is a very interesting tool to craft packets and send them in the wire. What i didnt found is the possibility to use this tool to capture incoming packets and redirect them to the right destination based on information found in the packet (http request). 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. What is your question exactly? Whether it is possible to do it? Or how it can be done?

Comment: Thank you Fabio, i would like to know if it is possible to do that using scapy. I am not sure if you can tell me how to do it but if you have some ideas that would very nice of you.

Comment: No, sorry, I simply found your question in a review and thought to ask you to clarify this, so that others can help you. I've never used scapy (or Python, for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You can capture packets with the [`sniff()`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing) function, modify them and send them with `sendp()`.

```
from scapy.all import *

while True:
    pkts = sniff(count=1)
    # do some stuff on pkts[0]
    sendp(pkts[0])
```